# will the mobile station continue to send probe request frame after associated to an ap?

Tags: wireless-networking, mobile-phone

The mobile device has already connected to an wifi network and associated an AP, will it still send the probe request frame?

As you will see the available AP list is refreshing even though you already connected to an AP.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on make and model, it possibly will. I've observed iPhones sending probe requests while associated with wifi. Presumably this could be for location services: knowing the APs in the area can help position a phone.